# Inserting rows into SQL server using Bulk copy from Spring JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jdbc, bcp

We can read/write data to sql server using JDBC, but for certain scalability reasons (volume & frequency), we want to use the bulk copy functionality.

According to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-bulk-copy-with-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20includes%20a,Java%20that%20provide%20similar%20functionality.), there is a SQLServerBulkCopy class. There are numerous examples, includind reading from other tables, and reading from files, but there is no example on how to insert an array of rows.

SQLServerBulkCopy has 3 writeToServer methods, which take Rowset, Resultset, and ISQLServerBulkData. Is converting our array/list into one of these classes the only way to do a bulk copy? Is there any other way to do it?

Would be glad of any pointers if you've come across this before.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/use-bulk-copy-api-batch-insert-operation?view=sql-server-ver15 ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is converting our array/list into one of these classes the only way to do a bulk copy? Is there any other way to do it?

Yes. The JDBC driver will also [use bulk copy API for batch insert operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/use-bulk-copy-api-batch-insert-operation?view=sql-server-ver15).